# React router and Multi step form managing page navigation and context state from json data

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-router, react-context

I'm creating an application where I am using React Router v6 with nested routes for a multi step form. The outer route functions as a layout wrapper for each of the forms contained within. I have the whole layout component wrapped with a context provider for management of state across each of the forms for managing the inputs and current page etc.

My react router looks something like below:

```jsx
     <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<Pages.Home />} />
        <Route path="form" element={<FormProvider><FormLayout /></FormProvider>}>
          <Route path="form1" element={<Forms.Form1 />} />
          <Route path="form2" element={<Forms.Form2 />} />
          <Route path="Form3" element={<Forms.Form3 />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<Pages.NotFound />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
```

The FormLayout contains buttons to navigate to the previous and next form component. I am using JSON supplied from the backend to determine the order of the pages. Something like:

```json
    {
        "form1" : {"prev": null, "next": "form2"m "title": "Enter your name"},
        "form2" : {"prev": "form1", "next": "form3", "title": "Enter your phone"},
        "form3" : {"prev": "form2, "next": null, "title": "Enter your email"}
    }
```

When the user navigates to form1, I look at the current url through the use of RR useLocation, find /form1, and determine the current page by looking at that key in the json data. I set that as the current page in state in my context which also provides the previous and next routes. My Form Layout can then use this state to know what pages are next and previous. The FormLayout Component looks like:

```jsx
    const FormLayout = () => {
        const {page} = useFormContext()
 
        return (
            <div>
                <Outlet/>
                <Link to={page.next}>
                    <button>
                        next
                    </button>
                 </Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

So this leads to my question:
**How can I manage page navigation without having to compare the current URL agains the json data and updating state?**
Any input on how to manage the navigation between forms would be appreciated. Thank you

While this is the behavior I expect, I don't think this is the best way to handle this. I don't want to hardcode the to="" routes in the Link Components on every Form Page and it's also important that the backend can change the order next/prev values on the json data if they want to reorganize the pages or change the title of the page etc.

Some alternatives are to remove the page state entirely, look at the route on EACH component and then determine the current page. I wouldn't then be managing state but it would be very redundant to have to look at the json body to determine the next and previous routes on every component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with this approach:

First, create a single nested inside the `form` path which accepts a URL parameter, like this:

```
<Route path="form" element={<FormProvider><FormLayout /></FormProvider>}>
  <Route path="/:formKey" element={<FormItem />} />
</Route>
```

In the `FormContext` I would save the whole object with the `questions` from the backend.

```js
{
  questions: {
    form1: {...etc},
    form2: {...etc},
    ...etc,
  }
}
```

The `FormItem` component would be like this:

```
const FormItem = () => {
  const { formKey } = useParams();
  const { questions } = useFormContext();

  const currentQuestion = questions[formKey]; // currentQuestion holds the data needed

  return (
    // current question implementation
  );
}
```